# How to commit and keep history only for the code?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I'm planning to use Github to store my website's code + images (logo, etc.) and when I make changes on my computer to `git pull` directly on the server (without having to SFTP all the time). The website is about 50MB but I make changes to some of the images every day and I don't want to fill the repo with unnecessary information. Is there a way for Github to keep history changes only for the code? The one thing I've found is `git commit --amend` but this won't keep any history.

Comment: have fun with `.gitignore` so that you can _avoid_ adding those files to the repo.

Comment: The thing is that I want to add the images to the repo so I don't have to upload them manually using SFTP.

Comment: If you think `.gitignore` doesn't fit your needs, it is time to think hard about your problem. You either want these images in git or you don't. You can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `.gitignore` to exclude your images. Otherwise just don't add them to the staging area.

Answer (score 0):

You could do so by storing the code and the *other stuff* in different directories. Then you can create a file named .gitignore to tell git what files/directories it should ignore. You can read the details of such a file [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).